# Drupal 7 comment.tpl.php overwrite for specific node type is not working

Tags: drupal, drupal-templates, drupal-comments

I've created a comment--track.tpl.php file in order to theme the comments of my "track" type node but I can't get Drupal to use it. It keeps using my themename/comment.tpl.php file. I made sure to clear cache, I also set the Devel module to rebuilt the theme registry on each load, but it just doesn't want to use my custom theme file. Anyone has any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

For Drupal 7 create a new file in your theme folder "comment--node-[type].tpl.php".
In your case file name should be "comment--node-track.tpl.php"

Answer (score 2):

The corresponding template suggestions seems to be missing in D7. See: [D7](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--comment--comment.module/function/template_preprocess_comment/7) vs. [D6](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--comment--comment.module/function/template_preprocess_comment/6). Not sure why and if that is a bug, but you can implement yourtheme_preprocess_comment() and add the following line yourself.

```
<?php
$variables['template_files'][] = 'comment-' . $variables['node']->type;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

For Drupal 7:

`comment--node-YOURNAMECONTENTTYPE.tpl.php`

If you want to override your `comment.tpl.php` in content type what has name `article`, 
you need to:

1. Copy original file-template **`comment.tpl.php`** from core Drupal 7
2. Paste it in your theme folder
3. Make a duplicate
4. Rename the duplicate to **`comment--node-article.tpl.php`**